# iOS UISlider VoiceOver Disable Saying Value

Tags: ios, accessibility, uislider, voiceover, audio-player

I have a `UISlider` that can seek in music.

Customer requests the value change of this slider not to be announced by `VoiceOver`.

Now the default behaviour of VoiceOver for `UISlider` is to announce the percent value and lower the music volume for that time. This is not good for me.

If I change the `accessibilityValue` to `@""`, then it makes a sound effect and also lowers the music volume. This is also bad.

I tried using the `UIAccessibilityTraitStartsMediaSession` and the `UIAccessibilityTraitPlaysSound` accessibility traits, but they don't effect this behavior.

What should I do?

Comment: What must your slider do exactly with VoiceOver ?

Comment: Seek in music. Meaning setting the current position of playback.

Comment: And you want to seek in music using the UISlider adjustable property with no sound, right ?

Comment: Yeah. That's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the native `UISlider` is a very good practice but not in your specific use case because you'll always have the sound effect you noticed when its value changes.

I suggest to create a [custom accessibility element](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-18230.html#UIAccessibilityElement) in a blank project as follows :

- First, create your slider in the Xcode interface builder with an outlet connection to your view controller.
- Implement a `UIAccessibilityElement` subclass that will represent your slider.

  ```
  class a11yMySlider: UIAccessibilityElement {

      var minimumValue = 0.0
      var maximumValue = 10.0
      var value = 5.0
      var theSlider = UISlider()

      init(in container: Any, with slider: UISlider) {
          super.init(accessibilityContainer: container)
          theSlider = slider
      }

      override var accessibilityTraits: UIAccessibilityTraits {
          get { return UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable }
          set {  }
      }

      override func accessibilityDecrement() {
          value -= (value == minimumValue) ? 0.0 : 1.0
          theSlider.value = Float(value)
      }

      override func accessibilityIncrement() {
          value += (value == maximumValue) ? 0.0 : 1.0
          theSlider.value = Float(value)
      }
  }
  ```
- Introduce your accessibility element in your view controller to simulate the physical slider with VoiceOver.

  ```
  class SliderNoSoundViewController: UIViewController {

      @IBOutlet weak var mySlider: MySlider!

      override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
          super.viewDidAppear(animated)

          let a11yElt = a11yMySlider.init(in: self.view, with: mySlider)

          a11yElt.accessibilityFrame = mySlider.frame
          self.view.accessibilityElements = [a11yElt]
      }
  }
  ```

I let you adapt the incoming parameters and the connection to the music playback inside your project but, as is, **the slider value changes are not vocalized by VoiceOver** as desired.

Moreover, [illustrations and code snippets](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html) *(ObjC and Swift)* are also available if you need more information to complete your implementation with VoiceOver.

Comment: You code makes VoiceOver stay silent indeed. However the volume of the music (played my AVPlayer) is still lowered. Also all other subviews of the container will be ignored by VoiceOver.

Comment: @GyörgyBenedek : your question only dealt with disabling the VoiceOver vocalization when the slider value changed. This solution works in a blank project and it's up to you to integrate it in your coding environment according to your purposes. Ask another question for your player (that is very specific)... and all the subviews are ignored here because they're not implemented in the `self.view.accessibilityElements` array in this case.

Comment: Okay, I will ask another question about the player. I have included all the subviews in the `accessibilityElements` array, now it's okay. But there is another fault. I use AutoLayout, and the frame of the `UIAccessibilityElement` doesn't match the frame of the `UISlider`. I tried `[UIWindow convertRect:toWindow:]`, but no use.